# $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)dt$, use the Mean Value Theorem to show that there exists $c\in [a,b]$ such that $\int_a^b f(t)dt=f(c)(b-a)$

Tags: calculus

[image]

Not really sure how to start this one... Any pointers?

Comment: What does the mean value theorem applied to $F$ tell you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well by the MVT, if $f$ were differentiable $$f(b) - f(a) = f'(c)(b-a)$$ for some $c \in (a,b)$

Now analogously apply the MVT to the function capital $F$ given in the problem.